# Cannot get FBA to properly authenticate

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

I'm trying to setup an external portal for our SharePoint 2013 site on server 2012 so external suppliers can access content. I've gotten FBA setup with the following guide:
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/

I've got my ASPNET database setup, and have one user added to it. Problem is no matter what I do, logging in fails. The webpage simply returns:

> "The server could not sign you in. Make sure your user name and
>   password are correct, and then try again."

However, the error log on the sharepoint server returns this:

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs

I can access the .net users tab just fine from IIS8 so long as I change my FBA provider to the default. From there I can add/delete users as well as roles, and the changes appear in my SQL database.

Other than this, my windows auth works fine on all my other web apps, and I get the prompt to select which type of authentication I would like to use.

Anyone know how I can narrow down what the possible cause is? The cryptic error message doesn't seem to be very helpful. All my web.configs match, as well as my STS config file.

Comment: it could be better if u can share membership part from all web app and STS. I am sure u must have done some mistake in webconfig file. Also check that Machinekey is same in al places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct @pushpendra that I had some web.config errors with my STS. Using this guide:
http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2011/05/sharepoint-2010-an-exception-occurred-when-trying-to-issue-security-token-the-server-was-unable-to-p-1.html

I managed to get detailed error reporting turned on. Once it was working, a quick glance at the event log on my SP server told me exactly what the problem was. Somehow I had ended up with multiple duplicate FBA membership and role provider statements. I removed  them one at a time until no more events were appearing, and at that point FBA started working properly.